# AWS s3 - > lambda -> sns = How to send url link with new image to android app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, android-notifications

New S3 item triggers lambda function. I'd like to somehow extract it's URL and pass it to sns as a link or something that can be opened from notification on Android phone. I can send notifications to phone at the moment but need to pass new element from S3. Does anyone have any ideas and is it possible to achieve like that?

Here's the code from my lambda function. It's in mess since i've been trying different combinations to attempt this:

```
import logging
import boto3

sns = boto3.client('sns')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


# Change topic, qos and payload
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #logger.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(file_key, bucket_name))
    presigned_url = s3.genereate_presigned_url(
       'get_object',
        Params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': file_key}
    )


    sns.publish(
        TargetArn='arn:aws:sns:eu...',
        Message=presigned_url
    )
```

error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'S3' object has no attribute 
  'genereate_presigned_url'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
  [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      14,
      "lambda_handler",
      "presigned_url = s3.genereate_presigned_url("
     ],
     [
      "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py",
      555,
      "__getattr__",
      "self.__class__.__name__, item)"
    ]
   ]
 }
```

Thanks to dpwrussell, I was able to extract url from test function and learned more about lambda and AWS. Below is updated version of the code and lambda trigger test.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import boto3

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

sns = boto3.client('sns')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')


# Change topic, qos and payload
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print(bucket_name)
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #logger.info('Reading {} from {}'.format(file_key, bucket_name))
    print('this will also show up in cloud watch')
    logger.info('got event{}'.format(bucket_name))
    logger.info('got event{}'.format(file_key))
    generate_presigned_url = s3.genereate_presigned_url(
        'get_object',
         Params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': file_key}
    )


sns.publish(
    TargetArn='arn.........',
    Message=generate_presigned_url
)
```

Test event:

```
 {
   "Records": [
 {
   "s3": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": "mybucket"
    }
   },
   "object": {
       "key": "Example.json.gz"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Obvious problem is generating the presigned URL outside of the handler, that should be inside as I assume you want a new presigned URL for each one. And at least tidy up the code and make it vaguely runnable. It's very difficult to diagnose problems when it's not.

Comment: Oh well! Im really sorry if its not readable to you. I created this post because ive never done this before and im not experienced in AWS. Dont understand why you bite!

Comment: How can anyone help you when they can't tell what the actual problem is?  `f` isn't in scope, indentation is broken in `publish_to_sns`, `record` isn't in scope.

Comment: Please have a look again. I think I fixed some of the issues

Comment: What input are you testing with?

Comment: Each new item is a .jpg format type.

Comment: What is the input to the lambda function?

Comment: S3 Object Put. Is this what you were asking about?

Comment: Your lambda function expects `event` (the input to the lambda function) to container a very specific structure. It looks highly likely that it does not have that structure, thus why you are seeing a `KeyError`. When you call the lambda function or run a test in the console, what inputs do you give it?

Comment: It was some random hello world test to trigger Google notification in earlier test. Now i've created new one: S3 put

Comment: If you use a hello world test, then it's not going to have the parameters that your lambda function is trying to read. I updated my answer.

Comment: I've changed the test trigger as you suggested but dont get idea about the key. Does it correspond to name of my image?

Comment: Put some diagnostics in your lamda function. print the `bucket_name` and `file_key`. Are they the correct arguments?

Comment: You misspelled `generate_presigned_url ` as `genereate_presigned_url`

Comment: I fixed all the issues highlighted and managed to get this workiing by providing input as you suggested. Many thanks for sorting me out and your patience too. One more thing... Test function does trigger notifications and im getting url on phone as well but only within the test event. Real object put does not trigger lambda now. Any idea where to look for that now?

Comment: Look at what input is present (by logging the contents of `event`) when you use the lambda for real. Probably the event structure is not what you expect. Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thanks got that working now! Hope it'll be usuefull to other users at some point...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the interface to `generate_presigned_url`.

It's:

```
presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object',
    Params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': file_key}
)
```

You also have a problem with your input. Your input needs to have a structure like this. Otherwise your lambda function will fail with that `KeyError` that your getting when trying to read these parameters from the event.

```
{
    "Records": [
        "s3": {
            "bucket": {
                "name: "mybucketname"
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "mybucketkey"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Marszal and @dpwrussell.
I am new to python and this post helped me to get the desired output. I am using Python 3.8 Runtime and was getting error with generate_presigned_url. Error looks like:

[ERROR] AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'genereate_presigned_url'

Also, I had to fetch file size. So I tried this simple approach to get the final URL and it is working.

```
import boto3
import logging
import json

sns = boto3.client('sns')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # retrieve bucket name, file_key and size from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print("Bucket Name: "+bucket_name)
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print("File Key: "+file_key)
    file_size = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['size']
    print("File Size: "+str(file_size)+"kb")
    s3url = "s3://"+bucket_name+"/"+file_key
    print("S3 URL: "+s3url)
```